# Nested expressions in equations

Tags: math-mode

Is it possible to type something like this (in math mode):

> A = B

and put something below the = sign (such as `x\rightarrow\something`)?

Comment: Please don't forget to also up-vote the answers you accept (as well as other good answers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\underset` from the `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$A\underset{x\to a}{=} B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I am not sure if I understood your intent correctly, though.